# Convex problem with concave constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, constraints

I have a simple question because I want to optimize an objective function which is non-linear and convex but is limited by 3 non-linear constraints, two of them are convex but the last is concave. Does it mean that my optimization problem is convex or not? I found the definition which shows that the optimization problem is convex when the objective function and all constraints are convex. Moreover, I found a similar topic: [Minimize convex function with concave equality contraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493633/minimize-convex-function-with-concave-equality-contraint) but for me is not clear.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: What exact optimization problem do you have?

Comment: Do you want the definition of my problem? In general, I want to minimize some metric which is non-linear and limited by 3 non-linear functions.

Comment: Nonlinear is too broad. Quadratic? Polynomial? Equality constraints? Inequality constraints?

Comment: In original form, the objective function had fractional form but I transformed it using Dinkelbach method and now I have following form: sum of linear variables minus q (where q is parameter) multiplied by sum of exp function, and 3  inequality constraints

Comment: Assuming that the concave function is used as $q(x) \leq 0$ leading to a feasible set which is not convex (unless $q(x)$ actually encodes something trivial which could lead to a trivial convex set) , the feasible set is not convex and it is consequently not a convex problem

Comment: In my case, the fractional form $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ was transormed into: $f(x) - qg(x)$, where $f(x)$ is sum of linear function e.g. $(x_1+x_2)$ and $g(x)$ is sum of exp function e.g. $\exp(y_1) + \exp(y_2)$

Comment: These details (and more) should be in the question itself. Please expand your question or risk closure.